# Missing class file when builidng for android - pusher_channels_flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, pusher

Error message when building for Android:

```
error: cannot access ConnectionEventListener
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.pusher.channels_flutter.PusherChannelsFlutterPlugin());
                                ^
  class file for com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionEventListener not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-channels-flutter/issues/27) adding the pusher java client dependancy in the app level build.gradle file fixes the issue.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:2.2.8'
}
```

Add to:

> your_project_folder/android/app/build.gradle

Comment: Append this code in your_project_foldder/android/app/build.gradle